# Failure in login, but only in Samsung

Tags: android, retrofit, samsung-mobile

In my app, I have a login process, once you are logged in, the app makes a call to the server to get a specific data:

```
Call<JsonObject> peticion= RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(InicioSesionGibActivity.this).login(imei, idCliente, user, encriptedPass);
peticion.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(final Response<JsonObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        String respoString=response.body().toString();
    if(response.isSuccess()){

        settings.edit().putBoolean("logueado", true).apply();

        Call<JsonPrimitive> peticion= RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(InicioSesionGibActivity.this).obtenerCodOrg(settings.getString("imei", ""), settings.getString("idCliente", ""));
        peticion.enqueue(new Callback<JsonPrimitive>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<JsonPrimitive> response2, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response2.isSuccess()) {
                    codOrg = response2.body().getAsLong();
                    settings.edit().putLong("codorg", codOrg).apply();
                    dropTables();
                    obtenerEntidades();
                }else{
                    //The execution gets here
                    Message msg=new Message();
                    msg.what=1;
                    loginHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    AlertDialog.Builder aDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(InicioSesionGibActivity.this);
                    aDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.error));
                    aDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.unknownerror));
                    aDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.si), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    aDialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                settings.edit().putBoolean("logueado", false).apply();
                Message msg=new Message();
                msg.what=1;
                loginHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                AlertDialog.Builder aDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(InicioSesionGibActivity.this);
                aDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.error));
                aDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.neterror));
                aDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.si), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                aDialog.show();

            }
        });

    }else{

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(InicioSesionGibActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.error));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.loginerror));
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Message msg=new Message();
                msg.what=1;
                loginHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                editTextUsuario.setText("");
                editTextPassword.setText("");

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    Message msg=new Message();
    msg.what=1;
    loginHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(InicioSesionGibActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.error));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.loginerror));
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
    builder.create().show();


}
});
```

The execution goes ok in all devices...except in my boss phone, a Samsung S7 (not the one that explodes). That happens if he executes it from APK. BUT, and this is the weird part, if I get the phone, and run the app from Android Studio, the execution goes perfectly, and i get the data just fine.

This is driving me nuts, because its hard to debug.

Someone has faced this problem?

If you need more data, or clarification, please ask.

Thank you.

Comment: When you run it from AS, are you running the debug or release build?

Comment: Both of them, I run in Debug mode and in Release mode and works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because it's a fast phone.  When you save data to shared preferences are you reading it back immediately?  You are using apply() which will store it in an asynchronous background thread and may not be there immediately if you try to read it back right away.

You may want to use commit() instead, which writes its data to persistent storage immediately in the current thread and will not continue execution until it is committed.

Comment: No, that data is stored for using it later, not immediately.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not, due to it only happening in a single device, we are leaving it aside for the moment, while I develop other things in the app. I will update if, once the moment has come, I manage to solve it